# Pass parameters from .net dll (or console app) to angular app (angular 5)

Tags: angular, angular5

Here is my scenario.. I have a scanner (PENTA Scanner) which I'll be using to scan Passport and DL. I have built an application which will extract required data (firstname,lastname,DOB) when a document is scanned. I have also built an application(using angular 5) that interacts with a rest service to fetch the data based on firstname, lastname and DOB.

Now, here is my question.. When I scan a document on the scanner, is there a way I can send the data to the angular app?

I want the app to listen to an event that'll be generated by scanner, grab the data and continue calling the rest service.

Thanks

Edit: Apologies... I should have provided this info earlier... I have used electron framework to build the app since I wanted to build a desktop application.

Comment: This is going to be very difficult be cause Angular runs inside a web browser, which is intentionally kept separate from the host OS. The only way I know of would be to put that data in the URL and have an Angular component read from there. But that is a very bad idea (IMO) because the URL is visible to anything watching network traffic and you're working with PII

Comment: The old way to do this is to periodically hit an endpoint from your client app and ask if there is any new information (An auto-refresh). The new way is with Web Sockets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used https://www.asp.net/signalr for that exact purpose.

Another way to do this (though a bit hacky in my opinion) is to use Redis as a publisher/subscriber https://redis.io/topics/pubsub

There are a lot of other methods, but those two are easy out of the box.

Comment: Thank you Juan. It took me some time to figure it out. I was able to get the solution using signalR

Comment: Glad it was helpful. If you agree that helped, accepting the answer an help others.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a link which has a detailed explanation on how signalR can be used along with Angular5 - https://medium.com/@rukshandangalla/how-to-notify-your-angular-5-app-using-signalr-5e5aea2030b2